# Protractor can't get value from executescript it returns a promise

Tags: angular, typescript, protractor

In protractor, I have this.

```
function getText(): string {
    return browser.executeScript(`return 'some text';`);
}
```

The first one returns a promise and I don't know how to get the value from a promise.

I then tried to do

```
function getText(): string {
    browser.executeScript(`return 'some text';`).then(function(result) {
        return result;
    });
```

The problem with the second one is that I can't find a way to make it asynchronous. It only returns when all my code is finished executing.

The thing I'm trying to achieve is :

```
let text = getText();
```

Hope someone can help as I couldn't find a working answer to this question.

Edit:
I couldn't find a way to place it in a variable outside the function. My current solution is:

```
browser.executeScript(`return 'some text';`).then(function(result) {
    console.log(result);
    //do your stuff here with the variable.
});
//can't find out how to use it outside the then function as other code runs first. But for now, that way works.
```

Comment: You can't transform an asynchronous call into a synchronous one. Just return a Promise<string>, and let the caller of your method deal with the returned promise.

Comment: your second example seems to miss `return` before browser.executeScript. So your function should return whatever executeScript returns. Otherwise it'll always be undefined

Comment: That doesn't work @Sergey Pleshakov

Answer (score 0):

You can use `async ... await` mechanism for working with promises:

```
async function getText(): Promise<string> {
  const text = browser.executeScript(`return 'some text';`);
  return text;
});

...
...

let text = await getText();
```

And if you don't want to wait while your `getText` method has been finished (I don't know why you need this strange thing) you can just not resolve the Promise:

```
let text = getText();
```

Comment: I'm getting Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'string'. And declaration or statement expected. Have you tested your own code?